# Matplotlib linegraphs start upruptly due to NaN values in data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have NaN values for few columns in the dataframe. Hence when I try to create a line graph of multiple columns, the graphs start abruptly. How do I avoid this? By filling NaN values in dataset with zeroes? Or is there any other way?

[image]

Look at the red line!

Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(70,40)) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.tick_params(direction='out', length=10, width=3,labelsize=35)
group_combined.plot(ax=ax,x='Date',y=['column1','column2'],linewidth=7.0)
ax.set_xlabel("date",size=40)
ax.set_ylabel("Number of orders",size=40)
ax.set_title("Distribution of orders over the month",size=50)
```

In my data, there are no NaN's in between. For a few columns, for first few dates NaN's might be present. Once value starts to come, no NaN's in between.

Python version: 3.6
Matplotlib version: 2.0.0

Comment: You need to clarify the behavior you want the line to have.

Comment: dropna(subset=[col1,col2....])

Comment: I just checked. For me the line does not start abruptly after the last NaN, but rather has 'holes' where the NaN values occur. Can you give us some example data, the code that you use to produce the plot and, possibly, your `python` and `matplotlib` versions?

Comment: So if you have NaNs in the beginning and you are wondering why the line starts only when you have finite values, what do you expect how the plot should look like?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to remove NaNs with using `numpy`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fix,axes = plt.subplots(1,2)

#setting up a simple function
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = np.exp(-x)

#inserting nan values at random places
#to get 'measurement data'
z = np.random.random(100)
y[z>0.9] = np.nan

#showing original
axes[0].plot(x,y)

#removing nans and replotting:
x = x[~np.isnan(y)]
y = y[~np.isnan(y)]
axes[1].plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:
[image: plot with nans and nans removed]
The left plot shows the data with NaNs, while on the right side they are removed.